# CSS -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio is disabling media query

Tags: android, html, css

I am making a site responsive for all devices. I have been testing it on Samsung Galaxy devices and getting stuck.

The galaxy S2 has a pixel ratio of 1.5 so I've tried to detect the device resolution using a pixel ratio but this seems to disable the media query.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (max-width: 320px) {}
```

The media query seems to work without the webkit pixel ratio.

```
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5)
```

Im using this for the viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Any help would be great, Thanks.

Heres the CSS code within in the media query.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (max-width: 320px) {

.menu > li.shopping-bag-item a > i.sf-cart, .mobile-cart-link i.sf-cart {
float: left;
margin-left: -66px;
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 157px;
width: 80px;
height: 32px;
display: block;
vertical-align: -3px;
/*background: url('/uploads/2014/06/cart.png');*/
}

#main-container{width: 328px;
}

.searchbar2 {
float: left;
margin-left:20px;
}

.searchbar3 input[type="text"] {
 background-color: white;
 border-color: rgba(5, 110, 207, 0.6);
 height: 23px;
 width: 133px;}

.searchsubmit2 input[type="submit"] {
 width: 147px;
 height: 32px;
 float: right;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 background-color: rgba(5, 110, 207, 0.6);}

 #logo {
 /*margin: 10px -89px 5px;*/
 float: none!important;
 width: 259px;
 margin-left: 18px}

 #megaMenu #megaMenuToggle {
 padding: 12px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: left;
 }

 #main-navigation {
 display: block;
 float: initial;
 margin: 0 20px;
 width: 239px;}

 h4.spb_heading span, h4.lined-heading span {
 width: 282px;}

 }
```

Comment: Please don't do this `user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1` It's not recommended and provides a very poor user experience.

Comment: Anyway, what happens if you **don't* use the `device- pixel-ratio` on the S2? You seem to be saying that it works if you remove it so, what is the actual issue?

Comment: The media query works fine in a browser without 'webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio' but once this is added the media query doesnt work. When using a Samsung Galaxy S2 the media query is ignored all together and refers back to 'max-width: 480px' media query. Half of the page is off the screen

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@media all and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (max-width: 320px),
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (max-width: 320px),
@media all and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (max-width: 320px) {}
```

or just

```
@media all and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (max-width: 320px) {}
```

that might not have worked because you were only targeting webkit based browsers (you may be using firefox on your phone)

Comment: This does seem to work. It still disables the media query on all browsers.

Comment: @Dharr88 what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt seem to work. Adding any pixel ratio to the media query stops the media query from working on all desktop browsers

Comment: can you post the code inside the mediaquery please?

Comment: Ive just added it in my question above. Its pretty standard CSS.